# Write error when importing large database to docker

Tags: mysql, database, import, docker, dump

I am importing a large application to Docker. Part of the application is a database. I have dumped the database into .sql file and now I am trying to import it to the docker container running official mysql image by mounting a directory from host machine and issuing command

```
mysql -u myUsername -p myDB < /mountdir/databasedump.sql
```

The database dump is very large, more than 10GB. Everything goes well for an hour, but then it issues error

```
loop: Write error at byte offset
```

I have a feeling that the size of the container runs out.

Is there a smarter way in accomplishing the dockerization of the database? In case not, how can I import the enormous database to the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that any container couldn't store the whole imported database, which was 26Gb and the error was due to the container ran out of disk space.

I solved the problem by mounting a directory from host as a external volume using the -v switch and editing the MySQL config to store its databases there.

This solution of course 'un-virtualizes' the database and it might be a security risk. Database server runs well virtualized though. In my situation the slightly weakened security wasn't an issue.

Comment: if you want the whole database inside the conatiner you just have to modify the docker daemon startup parameter and add the following`--storage-opt dm.basesize=<no of GB>G` the default is 10 GB

Answer (score 0):

[Don't use a devicemapper loop file for anything serious!](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/notes-on-fedora-centos-and-docker-storage-drivers/) Docker has warnings about this.

For a database that size you may want try [mounting a host directory as a volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) or [creating a local volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) to avoid docker's file system overhead. The two are essentially the same thing underneath.

If you are on RHEL, you can use an adequately sized LVM thin pool directly. There's a process [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37681340/1318694) for changing storage drivers.