# Docker hanging on "Extracting"

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04

On my local Macbook I can pull and build a particular Postgres container without issue.  However, on an Azure VM running Ubuntu 16.04 it hangs on "Extracting" until finally my ssh connection is closed.  How can I best diagnose this or what may be happening to cause this?

[image]

Comment: Is it a particularly large image on a tiny vm? It sounds kind of out of memoryish

Comment: I have similar issue, on big layers the docker pull usually hangs (sometimes even for a minute) and then it resumes and works correctly...

Comment: @Matt - It's a decently sized VM.  3.5 GB memory.  I've tried various images and the same thing happens.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with Azure.  As noted above, I use a standard Ubuntu image and install latest-stable Docker and Docker-compose myself.  I tried again using Azure's Ubuntu+Docker image, but then upgraded both Docker and Docker-compose.  I'm not having the issue anymore.

Comment: Maybe it's the Docker storage driver mixed with Azures storage backend then? Can you add the `docker info` from the server. Try mounting `/var/lib/docker` on temporary storage. Try it on premium disk. [Try moving to the `devicemapper` driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37681340/1318694)

Comment: Specifically the [`direct-lvm` mode for `devicemapper`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#configure-direct-lvm-mode-for-production)

Comment: same here but running docker on windows. I think it's an azure issue.

Comment: My work around was to launch a VM based on the Azure Ubuntu+Docker image, but that image ships with Docker-compose 2 and I need 3.  So I used that image, but upgraded the Docker-compose.  Then everything works.  My guess is that the Ubuntu+Docker image has some additional configuration to make Docker work on Azure.