# What is difference between docker pool and docker registry?

Tags: docker

I was asked this question in one interview and was not able to answer it. Also didn't find any relevant information regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

A Docker registry is, as said in the Docker documentation :

> [...] a hosted service containing repositories of images which responds to the Registry API.

There is no explicit definition in the documentation about a Docker pool. The part of the documentation where you can understand what is it, is the page [Use the Device Mapper storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/). In substance, the Docker pool is a storage pool used for image and container management.

Read also [What does “Thin Pool” in docker mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531525/what-does-thin-pool-in-docker-mean/49532550#49532550) for more information.