# How to solve /dev/mapper/docker full?

Tags: docker, device-mapper

I'm working on some docker container. 
While trying to install some python packages /dev/mapper/docker gets filled.
I read [Clean docker environment: devicemapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672018/clean-docker-environment-devicemapper/37681340), but this would stop ruining containers and impact the current workflow. How can I reduce it's size without effecting running containers ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker error : no space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604846/docker-error-no-space-left-on-device)

Comment: Note that there’s a non-zero chance that the full disk will cause Docker’s internal state to get corrupted, and you’ll have to delete your local Docker state.  If you’ve planned ahead so that there’s nothing precious in containers and you can recreate everything with `docker pull`, `docker build`, and host-directory volumes, this should be a non-event.  If you’re working interactively in containers a lot...sorry.